# How to make CDs not reflect?

Tags: reflection, glare

I’m having a party and my friend suggested to have a CD backdrop wall for photos. My concern is that if photos are taken with flash all the CDs would reflect in the pictures. Anyone have experience taking pictures of CDs? Is there something I can do to make them not reflect?

Answer (score 5):

If they do not reflect you will loose the effect of have them as backdrop, but:

- make them to be not parallel on the camera/flash
- use offcamera flash and move it on side
- use on camera flash and "move" the light to point to ceiling or diffuse the flash light
- do not use flash

...and probably several more methods